# prepending to a prev() with a condition in mind

Tags: jquery, image, joomla

I have a little issue:

```
<div class="items-row cols-1 row-2">
  <div class="item column-1">
    <h2>
        <a href="/ak/index.php/archwriting/8-2013-02-23-17-31-29">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </h2>
    <dl class="article-info">
        <dt class="article-info-term"></dt>
        <dd class="published">23/02/13</dd>
    </dl>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <div class="item-separator"></div>
</div>
<span class="row-separator"></span>
</div>
```

I  want to be able to check if the string "archwriting" is within the `href` attribute, and if so, to prepend an `<img>` above the `<h2>` tag.

I started with something like:

```
$('.item h2 a[href*="archwriting"]').prev().prependTo()
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: your string check and your selector don't match, do you want to filter `archwriting` or `archphoto`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.prev()` goes sideways, you want to go up using either `.parent()` or `.closest()`, the latter being preferable should you introduce more DOM hierarchy between the `<a>` and its enclosing `<h2>`.

The `.prepend()` and `.prependTo()` functions in jQuery add new elements as *children* of elements, whereas in this case you're more logically adding a *sibling*.

You can add a sibling element before a jQuery object using `.before()`

```
$('.item h2 a[href*="archwriting"]').closest('h2').before('<img ...>')
```

Comment: @mattytommo umm, yeah, not useful in this context though

Comment: Since I am considered an absolute beginner, I would love to know what's the proper syntax...

Comment: I disagree, I think OP may want `$('.item h2 a[href*="archwriting"]').parents(".item-column-1").prepend("<img....>")`

Comment: @mattytommo that only works if there's no other elements between the `.item` and the `h2`, i.e. it assumes that the `h2` is the first child.  The given answer puts the `img` _exactly_ before the `h2` as requested by the OP, regardless of other elements that might also appear before it.  Also, your `.parents()` selector is probably wrong.

Comment: True, then I guess we'd have to bulletproof your answer fully and do `.parents("h2:first")`

Comment: @mattytommo no, because you can't nest `h2` elements.  `.closest(h2)` would be preferable.

Comment: True, I would agree with that :)

Comment: @Alnitak Now that you've changed yours, I'll happily delete mine and give you your +1 :)